# Docker compose removing webserver also removes database

Tags: docker, docker-compose

sorry but I really can't figure out what's going on...

I have a service in mi `docker-compose.yml` called `engine` and another one called `database`, and `engine` has `depends_on` the `database` service...

Why if I remove the `engine` service, and then run `docker compose start database engine` I see:

```
 ⠿ Container codice_engine_1    Removed                                                                                                                                                   0.0s
 ⠿ Container codice_database_1  Removed
```

the actual command I'm running is the following:

```
docker compose rm -f engine \
  && docker compose build engine \
  && docker compose start database grafana engine
```

in the documentation I see as consequences of `depends_on` the following:

- docker-compose up starts services in dependency order. In the following example, db and redis are started before web.
- docker-compose up SERVICE automatically includes SERVICE’s dependencies. In the example below, docker-compose up web also creates and starts db and redis.
- docker-compose stop stops services in dependency order. In the following example, web is stopped before db and redis.

`docker-compose` is the following:

```
version: '3'

services: 
    database:
        image: postgres:13.2
        restart: always
        environment: 
           ...
        healthcheck:
            test: [ "CMD", "pg_isready", "-q", "-d", "postgres", "-U", "root" ]
            timeout: 45s
            interval: 10s
            retries: 10
        ports: 
            - 5433:5432
        volumes:
            - ./database/database.sql:/docker-entrypoint-initdb.d/create_tables.sql
            - ./database/data.sql:/docker-entrypoint-initdb.d/fill_tables.sql

    engine:
        build: ./engine
        restart: always
        volumes: 
            - .:/engine-code
            - ./config-examples:/config
        ports: 
            - 8080:8080
        depends_on: 
            - database
        environment: 
            - TZ=Europe/Rome
            ...

    grafana:
        image: grafana/grafana:latest
        depends_on: 
            - database
        ports:
            - "3001:3000"
        volumes:
            - ./grafana:/etc/grafana/provisioning/
```

Output:

```
➜  codice  docker compose rm -f engine
Going to remove codice_engine_1
[+] Running 2/0
 ⠿ Container codice_database_1  Removed                                                                                                                                                   0.0s
 ⠿ Container codice_engine_1    Removed 
➜  codice  docker container ls --all
CONTAINER ID   IMAGE          COMMAND                CREATED          STATUS                          PORTS     NAMES
47f8fed9eab8   bc8c9ea5532e   "/run.sh"              49 minutes ago   Exited (0) About a minute ago             codice_grafana_1
```

Comment: Could you post you docker compose file(s)?

Comment: @AntonioPetricca sure, thank you so much for your help, I really can't sort out this docker

Comment: After running `docker compose rm -f engine` what is the output of the command `docker container ls --all`?

Comment: @AntonioPetricca posted

Comment: Very very strange! This behaviour does not meet the speciifcation! :(

Comment: @AntonioPetricca yep, the problem is that rebuilding every time the DB (and populate it with a backup I made manually fo testing purpose) it's a bit too heavy for developing...

Comment: @AntonioPetricca btw, are you able to reproduce this behavior?

Comment: Unfortunately not at this moment!

Comment: @AntonioPetricca well thank you, I've opened an issue on github https://github.com/docker/compose/issues/8359... let's see what they say